# Не получается добавить дату в SQLite с помощью QtSql

Tags: python, sqlite, gui, pyqt, qtsql

Не получается добавить в базу данных **`дату`**.

Как правильно это делать с помощью `QtSql` ?

Есть такой код :

```
query.exec_("create table handbook(name_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
            "firstname varchar(20) not null,"
            "lastname varchar(20) not null,"
            "tel int(11),"
            "birth datetime,"
            "city varchar(20),"
            "address varchar(50),"
            "additional_info varchar(150))"
            )
query.prepare("insert into handbook(firstname,lastname,tel,birth) values('Vladimir','Putin',12345678911,:date")
query.bindValue(":date",datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
query.exec_()
```

Comment: Потому что в нем нет такого типа данных. Используйте строку

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Так как вы не предоставили минимальный воспроизводимый пример, я покажу вам то, что у меня есть. Думаю, что данный пример очень вам поможет.

```
import os
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore    import (QDate, QDateTime, QFile, QVariant, Qt)
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QDataWidgetMapper,QComboBox,
        QDateTimeEdit, QDialog, QGridLayout, QHBoxLayout, QLabel,
        QLineEdit, QMessageBox, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout)
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon,QPixmap,QCursor
from PyQt5.QtSql import (QSqlDatabase, QSqlQuery, QSqlRelation,
        QSqlRelationalDelegate, QSqlRelationalTableModel)


MAC = True
try:
    from PyQt5.QtGui import qt_mac_set_native_menubar
except ImportError:
    MAC = False

ID, CALLER, STARTTIME, ENDTIME, TOPIC, OUTCOMEID = range(6)
DATETIME_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"


def createFakeData():
    import random

    print("Dropping tables...")
    query = QSqlQuery()
    query.exec_("DROP TABLE calls")
    query.exec_("DROP TABLE outcomes")
    QApplication.processEvents()

    print("Creating tables...")
    query.exec_("""CREATE TABLE outcomes (
        id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE NOT NULL,
        name VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL)""")

    query.exec_("""CREATE TABLE calls (
        id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE NOT NULL,
        caller VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
        starttime DATETIME NOT NULL,
        endtime DATETIME NOT NULL,
        topic VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,
        outcomeid INTEGER NOT NULL,
        FOREIGN KEY (outcomeid) REFERENCES outcomes)""")
    QApplication.processEvents()

    print("Заполнение ...")
    for name in ("Resolved", "Unresolved", "Calling back", "Escalate",
                 "Wrong number"):
        query.exec_("INSERT INTO outcomes (name) VALUES ('{0}')".format(name))
    topics = ("Complaint", "Information request", "Off topic",
              "Information supplied", "Complaint", "Complaint")
    now = QDateTime.currentDateTime()
    query.prepare("INSERT INTO calls (caller, starttime, endtime, "
                  "topic, outcomeid) VALUES (:caller, :starttime, "
                  ":endtime, :topic, :outcomeid)")

    for name in ('Joshan Cockerall', 'Ammanie Ingham',
                 'Diarmuid Bettington', 'Juliana Bannister',
                 'Oakley-Jay Buxton', 'Reilley Collinge',
                 'Ellis-James Mcgehee', 'Jazmin Lawton'): 

        start = now.addDays(-random.randint(1, 30))
        start = now.addSecs(-random.randint(60 * 5, 60 * 60 * 2))
        end = start.addSecs(random.randint(20, 60 * 13))
        start=start.toString(DATETIME_FORMAT)
        end=end.toString(DATETIME_FORMAT)  
        topic = random.choice(topics)
        outcomeid = int(random.randint(1, 5))
        query.bindValue(":caller", name)
        query.bindValue(":starttime", start)
        query.bindValue(":endtime", end)
        query.bindValue(":topic", topic)
        query.bindValue(":outcomeid", outcomeid)
        query.exec_()
    QApplication.processEvents()

    print("Calls:")
    query.exec_("SELECT calls.id, calls.caller, calls.starttime, "
                "calls.endtime, calls.topic, calls.outcomeid, "
                "outcomes.name FROM calls, outcomes "
                "WHERE calls.outcomeid = outcomes.id "
                "ORDER by calls.starttime")
    while query.next():
        id = query.value(ID)
        caller = str(query.value(CALLER))
        starttime = str(query.value(STARTTIME))
        endtime = str(query.value(ENDTIME))
        topic = str(query.value(TOPIC))
        outcome = str(query.value(6))

        print("{0:02d}: {1} {2} - {3} {4} [{5}]".format(id, caller,
               starttime, endtime, topic, outcome))
    QApplication.processEvents()


class PhoneLogDlg(QDialog):

    FIRST, PREV, NEXT, LAST = range(4)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(PhoneLogDlg, self).__init__(parent)

        callerLabel = QLabel("&Caller:")
        self.callerEdit = QLineEdit()
        callerLabel.setBuddy(self.callerEdit)
        today = QDate.currentDate()
        startLabel = QLabel("&Start:")
        self.startDateTime = QDateTimeEdit()
        startLabel.setBuddy(self.startDateTime)
        self.startDateTime.setDateRange(today, today)
        self.startDateTime.setDisplayFormat(DATETIME_FORMAT)
        endLabel = QLabel("&End:")
        self.endDateTime = QDateTimeEdit()
        endLabel.setBuddy(self.endDateTime)
        self.endDateTime.setDateRange(today, today)
        self.endDateTime.setDisplayFormat(DATETIME_FORMAT)
        topicLabel = QLabel("&Topic:")
        topicEdit = QLineEdit()
        topicLabel.setBuddy(topicEdit)
        outcomeLabel = QLabel("&Outcome:")
        self.outcomeComboBox = QComboBox()
        outcomeLabel.setBuddy(self.outcomeComboBox)
        firstButton = QPushButton()
        firstButton.setIcon(QIcon("img/first.jpg"))
        prevButton = QPushButton()
        prevButton.setIcon(QIcon("img/prev.svg"))
        nextButton = QPushButton()
        nextButton.setIcon(QIcon("img/next.svg"))
        lastButton = QPushButton()
        lastButton.setIcon(QIcon("img/last.png"))
        addButton = QPushButton("&Add")
        addButton.setIcon(QIcon("img/add.png"))
        deleteButton = QPushButton("&Delete")
        deleteButton.setIcon(QIcon("img/delete.png"))
        quitButton = QPushButton("&Quit")
        quitButton.setIcon(QIcon("img/quit.png"))
        if not MAC:
            addButton.setFocusPolicy(Qt.NoFocus)
            deleteButton.setFocusPolicy(Qt.NoFocus)

        fieldLayout = QGridLayout()
        fieldLayout.addWidget(callerLabel, 0, 0)
        fieldLayout.addWidget(self.callerEdit, 0, 1, 1, 3)
        fieldLayout.addWidget(startLabel, 1, 0)
        fieldLayout.addWidget(self.startDateTime, 1, 1)
        fieldLayout.addWidget(endLabel, 1, 2)
        fieldLayout.addWidget(self.endDateTime, 1, 3)
        fieldLayout.addWidget(topicLabel, 2, 0)
        fieldLayout.addWidget(topicEdit, 2, 1, 1, 3)
        fieldLayout.addWidget(outcomeLabel, 3, 0)
        fieldLayout.addWidget(self.outcomeComboBox, 3, 1, 1, 3)
        navigationLayout = QHBoxLayout()
        navigationLayout.addWidget(firstButton)
        navigationLayout.addWidget(prevButton)
        navigationLayout.addWidget(nextButton)
        navigationLayout.addWidget(lastButton)
        fieldLayout.addLayout(navigationLayout, 4, 0, 1, 2)
        buttonLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        buttonLayout.addWidget(addButton)
        buttonLayout.addWidget(deleteButton)
        buttonLayout.addStretch()
        buttonLayout.addWidget(quitButton)
        layout = QHBoxLayout()
        layout.addLayout(fieldLayout)
        layout.addLayout(buttonLayout)
        self.setLayout(layout)

        self.model = QSqlRelationalTableModel(self)
        self.model.setTable("calls")
        self.model.setRelation(OUTCOMEID, QSqlRelation("outcomes", "id", "name"))
        self.model.setSort(STARTTIME, Qt.AscendingOrder)
        self.model.select()

        self.mapper = QDataWidgetMapper(self)
        self.mapper.setSubmitPolicy(QDataWidgetMapper.ManualSubmit)
        self.mapper.setModel(self.model)
        self.mapper.setItemDelegate(QSqlRelationalDelegate(self))
        self.mapper.addMapping(self.callerEdit, CALLER)
        self.mapper.addMapping(self.startDateTime, STARTTIME)
        self.mapper.addMapping(self.endDateTime, ENDTIME)
        self.mapper.addMapping(topicEdit, TOPIC)
        relationModel = self.model.relationModel(OUTCOMEID)
        self.outcomeComboBox.setModel(relationModel)
        self.outcomeComboBox.setModelColumn(relationModel.fieldIndex("name"))
        self.mapper.addMapping(self.outcomeComboBox, OUTCOMEID)
        self.mapper.toFirst()

        firstButton.clicked.connect(lambda: self.saveRecord(PhoneLogDlg.FIRST))
        prevButton.clicked.connect(lambda: self.saveRecord(PhoneLogDlg.PREV))
        nextButton.clicked.connect(lambda: self.saveRecord(PhoneLogDlg.NEXT))
        lastButton.clicked.connect(lambda: self.saveRecord(PhoneLogDlg.LAST))  
        addButton.clicked.connect(self.addRecord)
        deleteButton.clicked.connect(self.deleteRecord)  
        quitButton.clicked.connect(self.done)
        self.setWindowTitle("Phone Log")


    def done(self, result=None):
        self.mapper.submit()
        QDialog.done(self, True)


    def addRecord(self):
        row = self.model.rowCount()
        self.mapper.submit()
        self.model.insertRow(row)
        self.mapper.setCurrentIndex(row)
        now = QDateTime.currentDateTime()
        self.startDateTime.setDateTime(now)
        self.endDateTime.setDateTime(now)
        self.outcomeComboBox.setCurrentIndex(self.outcomeComboBox.findText("Unresolved"))
        self.callerEdit.setFocus()

    def deleteRecord(self):
        caller = self.callerEdit.text()
        starttime = self.startDateTime.dateTime().toString(DATETIME_FORMAT)
        if (QMessageBox.question(self,
                                "Delete",
                                "Delete call made by<br>{0} on {1}?".format(caller,starttime),
                                QMessageBox.Yes|QMessageBox.No) == QMessageBox.No):
            return
        row = self.mapper.currentIndex()
        self.model.removeRow(row)
        self.model.submitAll()
        self.model.select()
        if row + 1 >= self.model.rowCount():
            row = self.model.rowCount() - 1
        self.mapper.setCurrentIndex(row)

    def saveRecord(self, where):
        row = self.mapper.currentIndex()
        self.mapper.submit()
        if where == PhoneLogDlg.FIRST:
            row = 0
        elif where == PhoneLogDlg.PREV:
            row = 0 if row <= 1 else row - 1
        elif where == PhoneLogDlg.NEXT:
            row += 1
            if row >= self.model.rowCount():
                row = self.model.rowCount() - 1
        elif where == PhoneLogDlg.LAST:
            row = self.model.rowCount() - 1
        self.mapper.setCurrentIndex(row)


def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    filename = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "phonelog-fk.db")
    create = not QFile.exists(filename)

    db = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QSQLITE")
    db.setDatabaseName(filename)
    if not db.open():
        QMessageBox.warning(None, "Phone Log",
            QString("Database Error: %1").arg(db.lastError().text()))
        sys.exit(1)

    splash = None
    if create:
        app.setOverrideCursor(QCursor(Qt.WaitCursor))
        splash = QLabel()
        pixmap = QPixmap("im.png")
        splash.setPixmap(pixmap)
        splash.setMask(pixmap.createHeuristicMask())
        splash.setWindowFlags(Qt.SplashScreen)
        rect = app.desktop().availableGeometry()
        splash.move((rect.width() - pixmap.width()) / 2,
                    (rect.height() - pixmap.height()) / 2)
        splash.show()
        app.processEvents()
        createFakeData()

    form = PhoneLogDlg()
    form.show()
    if create:
        splash.close()
        app.processEvents()
        app.restoreOverrideCursor()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

main()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]