# Не работают внешние ключи при работе в приложении, написанном с помощью PyQt6

Tags: python, база-данных, pyqt, pyqt6, foreign-key

Данные в столбцах, которые являются внешними ключами одних таблиц, не изменяются при изменении данных в связанных первичных ключах других таблиц.

Базу данных sqlite я проверял в приложении DB Browser (SQLite). Там всё работает.

Вот основная часть кода:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import time, sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    splash = QtWidgets.QSplashScreen(QtGui.QPixmap("EJustice.png"))
    splash.show()
    con = QtSql.QSqlDatabase.addDatabase('QSQLITE')
    con.setDatabaseName('data.sqlite')
    con.open()
    window_1 = Window_1()
    window_2 = Window_2()
    window_3 = Window_3()
    window_4 = Window_4()
    window_5 = Window_5()
    window_6 = Window_6()
    window_7 = Window_7()
    window_8 = Window_8(window_7)
    window_9 = Window_9()
    window = Window(window_1, window_2, window_3, window_4, window_5, window_6,
    window_8, window_9)
    query = QtSql.QSqlQuery()
    query2 = QtSql.QSqlQuery()
    ico = QtGui.QIcon("icon.png")
    app.setWindowIcon(ico)
    time.sleep(3)
    window.show()
    splash.finish(window)
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: `QSqlTableModel` не отслеживает изменения в БД. Если вы внесли какие-то изменения вы должны подтянуть их вручную используя `select` или `selectRow`

Comment: @needKVAS, можете показать это на моём коде или написать свой пример, пожалуйста?

Comment: Я не могу показать на вашем коде т.к. плохо представляю структуру вашего кода. Вы уже делаете `self.stm.select()`, когда загружаете таблицу и удаляете записи. Когда вы изменяете данные в `ChangePrimaryKey` и `textEdited_2` вы должны послать сигнал, который соединён со слотом `Window_1`, обновляющем таблицу (таблицы).

Comment: McPoint, вы не предоставили [mcve], который демонстрирует проблему. Мне кажется, что пример https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1051467/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83-%d0%b2-sqlite-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%89%d1%8c%d1%8e-qtsql должен вам помочь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я понял в чем проблема. В бд sqlite по умолчанию выключена поддержка внешних ключей. Всё, что нужно было сделать - добавить две строчки после создания запроса query:

```
query.exec("PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON")
query.clear()
```

Answer (score 0):

Итак, вам нужно сделать так, чтобы ваши виджеты форм оповещали таблицу о том, что ей нужно обновить загруженные данные. Сделать это можно через механизм сигнал-слотов qt.

Для начала выгодно будет завести класс, содержащий сигнал, который будет оповещать о том, что нужно обновить таблицу.

```
class SuperForm(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    
    update_table = QtCore.pyqtSignal()
```

Далее, каждую форму, после работы которой требуется обновить таблицу наследуем от него. Например:

```
class Window_2(SuperForm):
```

А в методе после которого нужно обновить таблицу вызываем:

```
def ChangePrimaryKey(self):
    query2.clear()
    query2.prepare('update Студенты set ID_студента = ? where ID_студента = ?')
    query2.addBindValue(int(self.lineEdit_1.text()))
    query2.addBindValue(query.value('ID_студента'))
    query2.exec()
    quer = query.at()
    query.clear()
    query.exec("select * from Студенты")
    query.seek(quer)
    self.update_table.emit() #Запрашиваем обновление таблицы
```

Для того, чтобы данный механизм работал, нужно создать слот в классе с таблицей, который и будет осуществлять обновление:

```
class Window_1(QtWidgets.QWidget):

    def on_update_table(self):
        self.stm.select()
```

И подсоединить к нему сигналы:

```
class Window(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *other_window, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        
        for window in other_window:
            if issubclass(type(window), SuperForm):
                window.update_table.connect(other_window[0].on_update_table)
```

Для других ваших виджетов с таблицами можно поступить аналогично.

Это, так сказать, решение в лоб. Оно лишь демонстрирует принцип. Здесь многое не учитывается, например то, что таблицу в определённых ситуация вообще не нужно обновлять и т.п.

Comment: @McPoint, Вы хотите чтобы вместо ключей у вас были соответсвующие поля?

Comment: Я предположил, что вас не устраивает тот факт, что при открытом окне таблицы изменения в форме не отображаются в окне таблицы.

Comment: У меня почему-то таблицы не связаны друг с другом при работе в приложении. При обновлении одной, не изменяется связанная.

Comment: @McPoint, да, это происходить поскольку ваши таблицы лишь представляют результат запроса в бд. Они не знают , когда вы меняете данные в БД. Поэтому вы должны тем или иным способом обновить данные в таблицах вручную. Один из способов – использовать сигналы (Пример описан в ответе). В качестве альтернативного метода вы можете производить изменения таблиц через `QSqlTableModel` и [`QDataWidgetMapper`](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt6/api/qtwidgets/qdatawidgetmapper.html), но вам всё равно придётся оповещать *другие* таблицы об изменениях.

Comment: Я понял в чем проблема, оставил свой ответ.